# Why can't I answer a protected question?

Tags: support, protected-questions

I wanted to answer a question on a SE site, it says

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam
>   answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10
>   reputation on this site.

I have 101 rep on that site, and I can answer other questions so I'm not banned. So why can't I answer that one?

Comment: Your association bonus does not count for protected questions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ahhh ok

Comment: The key part of that message is "you must have *earned* at least 10 rep *on this site*".  In other words, association bonus doesn't count; just because you have rep somewhere else doesn't mean you understand what's expected at that site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters maybe it's time someone will start feature request asking to change the wording, at least make it "you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site (excluding bonuses)"? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I agree

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I did:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231012/clarify-reputation-requirement-for-protected-question

Comment: @Paul oops, didn't notice it was already suggested when posting above comment. Well, you did get some rep out of it so all is good. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, look at the date. You were my inspiration :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key word in that phrase is *earned*. I have over 200 rep, so I could join sites that I know nothing about, and I would essentially be useless there, so I couldn't contribute anything of worth to those questions.

Comment: I have 545 rep on stackoverflow, but I can't answer this question that requires only 10 rep earned. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430504/how-to-avoid-if-chains Is there something wrong with how protection is working?