# Duplicates in linked and related questions

Tags: bug, related-questions, linked-questions

I often browse the right side the of the page, looking for similar questions. ("I am interested in this question...what other questions should I read?")

Sometimes, I find the same question as both linked and related. ("Huh...I read a question just like this one...no it *was* this one...that's weird.")

Example from [Clarify reputation requirement for protected question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231012/clarify-reputation-requirement-for-protected-question):

[image]

Notice that [Allow people to answer protected questions if they have earned at least some amount of combined SE rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129214/allow-people-to-answer-protected-questions-if-they-have-earned-at-least-some-amo) shows up twice.

I am not sure if this is intentional behavior. If it is:

- I have mistagged this question.
- I do understand the "technical" correctness.
- I disagree with intended behavior, as I see at best only marginal benefit.

Comment: Pretty sure it's intended behavior.  "Linked" means that someone manually linked to it from the question or one of the answers or comments.  "Related" means that an automated algorithm determined there was a high degree of similarity.  **Neither implies the other.**  If clicking through to the same question twice is what you want to avoid, could there be a better mechanism for avoiding that?  For example, adding a little chain-link icon next to questions in the "related" list, if they also appeared in the "linked" list?  And a little percent (`%`) icon in the "linked" list, for "related".

Comment: @BenVoigt Looks like you already gave all points for transforming this into a [tag:feature-request]. +1